# How to get 0 in COUNT from different months and status?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, left-join, web2py

I have two tables `item` and `status`.

`item` is a table like this:

```
id   date          status_id
1    10-02-2013    1
2    11-02-2013    1        
3    11-03-2013    2        
...  ...           ...
```

`status` is a table like this:

```
id      status_name 
1       first       
2       second   
3       three
...     ...
```

I'd like as a result something like this:

```
month   status   total
2       first    2
2       second   0
2       three    0
3       first    0
3       second   1
3       three    0
```

I am using SQLite through web2py:

```
select 
      month, status.status_name, ifnull(total, 0)
from 
     status
left join                           
     (select 
            status.id,
            strftime('%m', date) as month, 
            status_name as status,
            count(status_name) as total                     
      from 
          status 
      inner join 
          item
      on status.id = item.status_id
      group by nombre, web2py_extract('month', date)
      ) sub                  
on sub.id = status.id
```

I am using the function `web2py_extract` to group `date` by month.

My result is the next:

```
month   status   total
2       first    2
3       second   1
```

However, I am not getting the rows with empty value. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `cross join` and then `left outer join`:

```
select m.month, s.status, coalesce(i.cnt, 0) as cnt
from (select distinct strftime('%m', date) as month from item) m cross join
     (select id, status from status) s left outer join
     (select strftime('%m', date) as month, status_id, count(*) as cnt
      from item i
      group by strftime('%m', date), status_id
     ) i
     on i.month = m.month and i.status_id = s.id;
```

The `cross join` creates all combinations of month and status.  The `left join` brings in the count.  The `coalesce()` converts `NULL` to `0` when there is no match.

Comment: Great! Also works with `natural join` insted of `cross join` and `left join` instead of `left outer join`.

Answer (score 0):

The table with the non-matching values you want anyway must be on the left side of the LEFT JOIN.
This means you need `item LEFT JOIN status` in the inner query.
(The outer query does not need an outer join.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTH(date) as Month, Status.status_name, COUNT(*) as Total 
FROM  Item 
LEFT JOIN Status on Item.status_id = Status.id
```